# some bug in my code while working in as 3.0 while integrating with php

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to enhance db connection via php. For that i create tables in mysql and created corresponding php. it was working in Xamp. Then i try to create the flash file i.e fetching data's into list from db. This is my as file

```
var theXML:XML = new XML();
theXML.ignoreWhite=true;
theXML.onLoad=function(){
    var i;
    var nodes=this.firstChild.childNodes;
    for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){

// Error        **theList.addItem(nodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue,i);**
    }
}
theXML.load("http://localhost/praven/product.php");
```

in output window it shows " Incorrect number of arguments. Expected no more than 1"

Comment: You do know this is actionscript 2?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    var theXML:XML = new XML();
    theXML.ignoreWhite=true;
    theXML.onLoad=function(success){
      if(success){
        var i;
        var nodes=this.firstChild.childNodes;
        for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){

            theList.addItem({label:nodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue,data:i});
        }
    }
    else{
    trace("Error");
    }

}
theXML.load("http://localhost/praven/product.php");
```

Comment: thanks mgraph but still tere is some issue. now its showing    TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
 at List_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: while i run the fla file it shows this error in output window... TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
 at List_fla::MainTimeline/frame1(). its not showing error in which line. as im newbie to flash. i cant rectify it

Comment: @PraveenBabu wait are you using as2 or as3 because this script is for as2 not as3

Comment: ohh thanks mgraph i was working this in AS3. ty for information. i will try this code in AS2. :)

Answer (score 0):

this.firstChild.childNodes; works with XMLDocument and you are using XML. Just convert your XML to XMLDocment if you want to use XMLNodes.

Comment: There is no need to convert into xmldoc because of output of PHP --> view pagesource is xml format. i didnt mention php code here. but i made into xml format. anyway i got output with help of mgraph. actually i tried tat code in as3. tat is the problem and i rectify it and got output. thank you for trying to help me.